# Accessing Radio button status using javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have created a radio button widget using struts2. I want to retrieve the selected radio button value using javascript function. Please help me. The below code retrieves only the first element.

```
function getAddress()
{
    var add=document.getElementById("add").value;
    alert(add);
    window.opener.setAddress(add);
    window.close();

    return true;
}
</script>
<body>
<s:action name="Address" id="addlist"/>
 <s:radio label="Address" name="add" list="employeeDetail.addlist">
  <br>
 </s:radio>
<input type="button" name="nextButton" id="nextButton" value="Select"
                 onclick="javascript:getAddress();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the rendered html, please? JavaScript works client side, therefore the struts(?) code is irrelevant; it's what it produces that matters.

Comment: function getAddress()
{
 var add=document.getElementById("add").value;
 alert(add);
 window.opener.setAddress(add);
 window.close();

 return true;
}
</script>
<input type="radio" name="add" id="addbangaloresada" value="bangaloresada"/><label for="addbangaloresada">bangaloresada</label>
<input type="radio" name="add" id="adddass" value="dass"/><label for="adddass">dass</label>
    </td>
</tr>


<input type="button" name="nextButton" id="nextButton" value="Select"
     onclick="javascript:getAddress();" />
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks, but could you edit that into the question, where it's more readable, and visible? Click the 'edit' link below the tags. :)

Comment: SOLVED.. Used getElementsByName("add") and then used the checked method to get the selected one from the array having radio button group elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have given the name "add" to the radio element, you need to either replace it with id="add" or have both - as you are trying to get element by id and it currently has no id.

edit--------
Seeing the rendered HTML it seems that getting the element value by name would be better suited getElementsByName("add")

Comment: added the id.. But still getting only the first value of the radio button group.. How to get the one which is selected ??

Comment: if they all have the same id, then which ever is selected should be the value. Is this a live page we can view?

Comment: as they have different id's try getting the element by name getElementsByName("add")

Comment: Looking into jQuery, will save you a lot of time.

Comment: SOLVED.. Used getElementsByName("add") and then used the checked method to get the selected one from the array having radio button group elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have given radio button name as "add" but while accessing in javascript you are trying to access it by id, i.e

```
document.getElementById("add");
```

Either change `document.getElementById("add")` to `document.getElementByName("add")`
or you can also give radio button an id as "add" and then use your same code;
i.e., add id as follows and change value of name attribute.

`id="add" name="addValue"` in struts radio tag.

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create the function `getSelectedRadioValue` and call the function with the radio group name.

```
function getAddress()
{
    var add=getSelectedRadioGroupValue("add");
    alert(add);
}

//Method to return radio group value. default 0
function getSelectedRadioGroupValue(name){

    var radioGrArr = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var value = '0';
    for (var i=0; i < radioGrArr .length; i++) {
    if (radioGrArr [i].checked == true) {
            value = radioGrArr [i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Don't write only code. add some explanation as well.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much for comment.